# Keno UI TreeView Angular JS:- How to select the newly added item?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I have an issue. I can add a new item to the tree view using this [TreeView With AngularJS](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/angular) but i can't make this new item the selected one. **How to select this new item** ?
This is my code that is used to add new item to the tree.

```
var newCreatedCompanyHierarchyItem = this.createNewCompanyHierarchyItem();
        this.$scope.tree.append(newCreatedCompanyHierarchyItem,   this.$scope.tree.select());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The append() method has a callback parameter that gets called once the new item has been added(after fetching siblings remotely if required).  The parameter to the callback is the appended `<li>` element which can be used to select it:

```
var addedElement = this.$scope.tree.append(newCreatedCompanyHierarchyItem, this.$scope.tree.select(), function (e) {
    $scope.tree.select(e);
}));
```

Simple example: http://dojo.telerik.com/@Stephen/OxOMe